# KeyError: 'for' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm getting KeyError : for

```
X = [[word2idx[token] for token in d.split()] for d in desc]
```

desc contains words or tokens , How do i solve this error?

Comment: Please provide your input list

Comment: Give proper description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some of the words or token do not have a value in word2idx

Use `dict.get` to prevent the error.

**Ex:**

```
X = [[word2idx.get(token, None) for token in d.split()] for d in desc]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, But why was i getting that error?

Comment: Some of the token or words are not in the dictionary you are looking for. Ex the key `for` is not in dict `word2idx`

Comment: actually it doesnt let me accept the solution within 8 minutes